# Kendo Grid Inline edit update. Server responded with status 404

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, razorengine

Kendo grid inline edit shows

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

multiple time per click in the browser console. The post url it is pointing to is not same as the one I entered in the update action. The screenshots show the browser console and source code:
[image][image]

[image]
It seems to be calling the page url as shown in the first screenshot instead of the url for update.action. That's strange.

Comment: Share the code in the post...

Comment: Backend or html?

Comment: Provide your controller code too.

Comment: @AnastasiosSelmanis, I have just added the backend code for the update operation. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The reason I wanted to see your controller code was to see the result you are sending back. First of all with debugging do you enter the controller method? From what I see you should probably enter it. (If so the method is correctly called). From there I need to see what are you sending back. You should probably send back a jsonResult to the DataSource Request with the model that was submitted.